# Grid in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

The Book Ship application will provide users with an interface to enter Target numbers by first selecting the Fiscal Year, Quarter, Business Unit, and Region filters.  Data will be preloaded in Salesforce for all Region, BU, Product, and Week combinations at the beginning of each Fiscal Year, so the user would not need to create any records.  They would be presented with the screen below that contains Targets in a grid format that the user would fill out like a spreadsheet. When the “Save” button is selected, the Target data that has been changed will be updated on the object’s records. 
 
There is a monthly total for the weeks that fit into the month, and a quarterly total in the gray columns.  There are also totals for the weekly product Targets for each Region.  The Grand Total is summed at the very bottom row of the table.  These total fields will be output data only.  Users will not be able to override the calculations.
 
The previous weeks values will be read-only.  The user can enter data for any future week in the current fiscal quarter, but cannot for future quarters.

How to get the grid part in visualforce page with rows and columns summarized as shown in below pic.I could only get upto buttons part and not able to proceed further.

Below here is sample Book Ship Metric Record from where we retrieve values and display in vf page
[image: Sample Book Ship Metric Record]

Below here is how vf page should look a like
[image: Book Ship App]

Here is what I have achieved till now

[image]

```
public with sharing class BookShipMetricsController {

public String selectedQuarter{get;set;}

public String selectedFiscalYear{get;set;}

public BookShipMetricsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}

public List<SelectOption> getQuarter(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('Q1','Q1'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Q2','Q2'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Q3','Q3'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Q4','Q4'));
    return options;

}

public List<SelectOption> getFiscalYear(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('2015','2015'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('2016','2016'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('2017','2017'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('2018','2018'));
    return options;

}

public PageReference TargetValues() {

    return null;
 }  

}
```

---

```
 <apex:page standardController="Book_Ship_Metric__c" extensions="BookShipMetricsController">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>

  <table width="100%">
   <tr>
   <td>
   <apex:outputLabel value="Business Unit" ></apex:outputLabel>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Book_Ship_Metric__c.Business_Unit__c}">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!TargetValues}" reRender="resultTable" />
   </apex:inputField> 
   </td>
   <td>
   <apex:outputLabel value="Region" ></apex:outputLabel>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Book_Ship_Metric__c.Region__c}">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!TargetValues}" reRender="resultTable" />
   </apex:inputField>
   </td>
   <td>
   <apex:outputLabel value="Quarter" ></apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedQuarter}" size="1" multiselect="false">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Quarter}"></apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList> 
    </td>
    <td>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Fiscal Year" ></apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedFiscalYear}" size="1" multiselect="false">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!FiscalYear}"></apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>       

  <apex:outputPanel id="resultTable">
   <table>

  </table>
 </apex:outputPanel>   
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: sf.dev, what's your question ?

Comment: @Samuel De Rycke How to get the grid part in visual force page with rows and columns summarized as shown in pic

Comment: why don't you use standard summary reports?

Comment: @ Nick Cook We want the users to update the target field values for multiple records on the visualforce page

Comment: @sf.dev Truthfully, if you are looking at getting this similar view with a visualforce page that is responsive, I would look at javascript libraries that do these type of table summary calculations on the fly rather then having to always go back to the controller, and have a user click save at the end. You can get away with standard HTML tag / tables and just use the `apex:repeat` tag to loop through your records.

Comment: Here are some javascript libraries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192982/javascript-table-libraries#7193156